# How to Assert a Text In Regional Language like Hindi in Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I want to validate a text but its in Hindi in the website i am working on .
The code goes this way

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(
            By.xpath("/html/body/nav[1]/div/ul/div/div/li[2]/form/input[4]"),
            "हिंदी"));
    System.out.println("Language changed to "+ landingpage.getHindiLanguage().getText());
```

And The Output I Get is

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for text ('?????') to be present in element found by By.xpath:
```

How shall i approach this?

Comment: Please show us the HTML source of relative element first.

Comment: The ??? is because your console can't render the correct characters.

Answer (score 0):

From your xpath assuming you are trying to getText from a input tag

Input tag stores the value in `value` attribute so you should get the value from the attribute instead of using `getText()` use
`webelement.getAttribute("value")` this will return values stored in input field

`getText()` will works only for HTML element which store values in node.

Like `p` tag as shown below

`<p>PARAGRAPH</p>`